# How do I correct issue with Imagemagick not resizing images over 1024?

Tags: 7, media

When I resize a very large smartphone image to 1000 x 1000, the resulting size is 160 kb. When I resize the same large image to 1250 x 1250 the resulting size is 1.2 mb. The correct resize should be 250 kb. Any thoughts? I am using Drupal 7.41 and [imagemagick](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagemagick) module 7.x-1.0

Comment: What is the original image size?

Comment: Original imagesis 3.75 MB 3264x2448 72dpi. I have imagemagick toolkit quality set at 72%